# Chrome extension debug "GET chrome-extension://invalid/ net::ERR_FAILED"

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm developing a Chrome extension and recently I've been getting this error, in the extension's `background.js` page:

```
GET chrome-extension://invalid/ net::ERR_FAILED
```

I can't seem to find much information on how to debug this and prevent it. The initiator is blank, so I can't find what code in the `background.js` is actually causing this request.

[image: chrome]

Request details don't show anything either...

[image]

Any ideas on what this could be??

Comment: Can you post your background.js file?